# printing out lists and dictionaries with indents in python

Tags: python

Is there any way to print lists or dictionaries (or a list with a dictionary in it) in a human readable format (multi-line,indented) instead of just on one long line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out pprint (pretty printer): http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html